# How to import snapshot when ES does not recognize the snapshot?

Tags: elasticsearch

My ES indexes are broken and I want to restore them via a snapshot.

My snapshots are hosted in Amazon S3. The last was made with:
`GET /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_traces_291215/_status?pretty'`

But when I try to restore it with :

`POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_traces_291215/_restore`

ES throws me:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "repository_missing_exception",
            "reason": "[my_backup] missing"
         }
      ],
      "type": "repository_missing_exception",
      "reason": "[my_backup] missing"
   },
   "status": 404
}
```

Maybe it is normal as my indexes are broken ES may has lose the snapshot infos.

Here is the status of my indexes:

```
red    open traces_v2 3 1                 
red    open traces_v1 3 1                 
yellow open users     3 1 2 0 6.2kb 6.2kb
```

`curl localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v` gives me:

```
name            component version type url            
Infant Terrible head      master  s    /_plugin/head/ 
Infant Terrible license   2.2.0   j
```

and `GET /_snapshot/my_backup/` gives me:

```
{
   "my_backup": {
      "type": "s3",
      "settings": {
         "bucket": "backup-es-ranger",
         "secret_key": "...",
         "region": "eu-central-1",
         "access_key": "..."
      }
   }
}
```

So how I could restore my data in this case? Thanks you for your help.

Comment: What do you see when running the following command: `curl localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that you don't have the [S3 repository plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws#aws-cloud-plugin-for-elasticsearch) plugin installed.

It is necessary in order to support [S3 repositories](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.x/cloud-aws.html).

Simply go into your ES home folder and install it like this:

```
bin/plugin install cloud-aws
```

Then restart ES and it should work.

Comment: This throws me an error:

$ bin/plugin install repository-s3
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.elasticsearch.common).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
-> Installing repository-s3...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/repository-s3/2.2.0/repository-s3-2.2.0.zip ...
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information

Comment: Would it not rather `bin/plugin install cloud-aws`  ? (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/cloud-aws.html)

Comment: Thx Val. I progress. Now I can access snapshots. But restoring them with: `POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_traces_291215/_restore` gives me: {
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "process_cluster_event_timeout_exception",
            "reason": "failed to process cluster event (restore_snapshot[snapshot_traces_291215]) within 30s"
         }
      ],
      "type": "process_cluster_event_timeout_exception",
      "reason": "failed to process cluster event (restore_snapshot[snapshot_traces_291215]) within 30s"
   },
   "status": 503
}

ES does not find it ?

Comment: It seems that your cluster is unresponsive... Is it green or at least yellow with all primary shards assigned?

Comment: I pasted the status in my question for readability. The traces indexes are red.

Comment: Maybe it worth to delete all indexes and restore? But in this case, how to preserve snapshots repo informations?

Comment: you can certainly delete your red index, the snapshot repo is safe since it's  stored in `_snapshot, i.e. not in that index

Comment: well, maybe my problem is somewhere else. Even `DELETE /traces_v1` gives me a 503 error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102683/discussion-between-danieln-and-val).